# How to access meta-data tables in on a different schema to a Spring Boot + Batch application?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-batch

In my Spring Boot app, I like to use Spring Batch meta-tables with a specific schema. The [documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/reference/html/configureJob.html#repositoryTablePrefix) suggests to use a table prefix.

I tried to add `batch.table.prefix=abc.BATCH_` to the property file. I also tried to override the configuration:

```
@Configuration
@EnableBatchProcessing
public class BatchConfig {

    @Bean
    public JobRepository jobRepository(DataSource dataSource) throws Exception {
        final JobRepositoryFactoryBean factory = new JobRepositoryFactoryBean();
        factory.setDataSource(dataSource);
        factory.setTablePrefix("abc.BATCH_");
        factory.setTransactionManager(transactionManager(dataSource));
        factory.afterPropertiesSet();
        return factory.getObject();
    }

    @Bean
    public JobExplorer jobExplorer(DataSource dataSource) throws Exception {
        final JobExplorerFactoryBean factory = new JobExplorerFactoryBean();
        factory.setDataSource(dataSource);
        factory.setTablePrefix("abs.BATCH_");
        factory.afterPropertiesSet();
        return factory.getObject();
    }

    @Bean
    public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager(DataSource dataSource) {
        return new DataSourceTransactionManager(dataSource);
    }

    ...
}
```

But I always get the error: 
Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Table "BATCH_JOB_INSTANCE" not found; SQL statement:
SELECT JOB_INSTANCE_ID, JOB_NAME from BATCH_JOB_INSTANCE where JOB_NAME = ? and JOB_KEY = ? [42102-182]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think with `@EnableBatchProcessing` the best way to change the repository/explorer is to provide your own `BatchConfigurer` (just a bean definition). You can easily extend one of the existing instances.

Answer (score 0):

In my case , I have used mysql as database ,I got this error .I resolved like this:

1.Copy mysql(eg.mongo db,hsqldb etc) queries (create and insert query) from following jar spring-batch-core jar .
 [image]

[image]

2.Paste the insert and create queries in database which you have used (like mysql ,mongo , hsqldb etc) and execute them all , required table will be created and data within table will be inserted in corresponding table.

3.Run your batch program ,it will find "batch_job_instance" table and other required tables.

Comment: This is manual, but is there any way if we can do it manually ?